# Robot_localization unable to publish tf map  odom

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to set up robot_localization for my own robot. it’s a differential robot with jetson nano and ros melodic.
It has Wheel Odometry, IMU and GPS
When I fuse only Wheel Odometry and IMU, it’s work very well

And then I am running two instances of robot_localization
ekf_local fuses only  the imu (imu/data) and the wheel odometry (/odom) to provide the tf odom -- base_link
ekf_global  fuses  the imu (imu/data), the wheel odometry (/odom) and the odometry from gps (/odometry/gps)
to provide the tf map--odom

Unfortunately I can’t obtain the tf  map --> odom

I have this error with roswtf

```
ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/ekf_local] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/ekf_global]
 * node [/ekf_global] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/ekf_local]
```

It’s very clear but I have been searching for a long time for this problem but still have not found a solution.
Now, I’m running out of ideas and that’s why I’m asking for help.

Thanks for advance for help

These are the main parameters of my configuration:

/odom

```
header: 
  seq: 2353
  stamp: 
    secs: 1621269914
    nsecs: 517945051
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
position: 
  x: 1.42776163451
  y: 1.05459486876
  z: 0.0
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: -0.0
  z: -0.969285642944
  w: -0.245937679876


 covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

/imu/data

```
header: 
  seq: 23430
  stamp: 
    secs: 1621270028
    nsecs: 842851010
  frame_id: "imu"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0321049389572
  y: -0.0256961583669
  z: 0.862560831451



 w: 0.50427947845
orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.00555555555556
  y: 0.00555555555556
  z: -0.00111111111111
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration:



  x: -0.03
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.1
```

/odometry/filtered_global

```
header: 
  seq: 9837
  stamp: 
    secs: 1621270122
    nsecs: 593107462
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 


  position: 
  x: 3.1402834907
  y: -0.174301283379
  z: 0.363305654322
```

orientation:

```
  x: -0.0337846203609
  y: -0.0230412789275
  z: -0.733087734948
  w: 0.678903580608
```

/odometry/gps

```
header: 
  seq: 198
  stamp: 
    secs: 1621270660
    nsecs: 123980998
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: ''


  pose: 
  pose: 
position: 
  x: -47.288572479
  y: 34.9779323968
  z: 0.0

orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 1.0

  covariance: [4.494400000000001, -6.32346808388906e-17, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.3555156131737614e-16, 4.494400000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 17.977600000000002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

launch file

```
 <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_gps"   args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  base_link  gps" />

 <!--   ********************************   -->
  
     <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_imu"   args="-0.015 0.12 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0   base_link  imu" /> 

 <!--   **************************  Navsat_transform_node  **************************  -->
    <!--
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" respawn="true" output ="screen">
    -->
 
    <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" clear_params="true" output ="screen">


    <param name="frequency" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="delay" value="3.0"/>

    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0.046"/>
    <param name="yaw_offset" value="1.57"/>
    <param name="zero_altitude" value="true"/>

    <param name="broadcast_cartesian_transform" value="false"/>



 <param name="publish_filtered_gps" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="false"/>
    <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false"/>

    <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu/data" />
    <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/fix" />
    <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odometry/filtered_global" />

    </node>
   
  <!--  ***************   LOCAL  EKF LOCALIZATION    ***********************       -->
     
     <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_local" clear_params="true">

        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mybot_navigation)/config/ekf_local.yaml"/>

        <param name="imu0"  value="/imu/data"/>
        <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
  
    </node>

   <!--  ***************   GLOBAL  EKF LOCALIZATION    ***********************       -->
     
     <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_global" clear_params="true">

        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mybot_navigation)/config/ekf_global.yaml"/>

        <param name="imu0"  value="/imu/data"/>
        <param name="odom0" value="/odom"/>
        <param name="odom1" value="/odometry/gps            "/>

        <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_global"/>
  
    </node>
```

ekf_local

f

```
requency: 30

sensor_timeout: 0.1

two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false

publish_tf: true

map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link

worl_frame: odom


  
    # Configuration Odometry
    odom0: odom
    
    odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
                   false, false, false,
                   true, true, true,
                   false, false, true,
                   false, false, false]

odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_differential: false
odom0_nodelay: true
odom0_relative: false

# Configuration IMU

imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true, false,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              true, true, true]


imu0_differential: false
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 10

process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]


initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]
```

ekf_global

```
frequency: 30

sensor_timeout: 0.1

transform_time_offset: 0.2
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
two_d_mode: false

publish_tf: true

map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link

worl_frame: map


# Configuration Odometry
odom0: odom

odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, true,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]

odom0_differential: false
odom0_nodelay: true
odom0_relative: false
odom0_queue_size: 10


# Configuration GPS
odom1: odometry/gps

odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]

odom1_differential: false
odom1_nodelay: true
odom1_relative: false
odom1_queue_size: 10

# Configuration IMU
imu0: imu/data

imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true, false,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              true, true, true]


imu0_differential: false
imuO_nodelay: true
imu0_relative: false
imu0_queue_size: 10
```

process_noise_covariance: [1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    1e-3, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.5, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.5, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.1, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,    0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3, 0,
0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.3]

```
initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1.0,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1.0,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1.0,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1.0, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1.0, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1.0]
```

`rqt_graph`:

[image: rqt_graph]

`tf_tree`:

[image: tf_tree]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378462/robot_localization-unable-to-publish-tf-map-%EF%83%A0--odom/) by [Bertrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/74630/bertrand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-05-18**:
Can you please add a tf tree and a node graph?  (e.g. rqt_tf_tree/rqt_graph)

**Comment by [Bertrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/74630/bertrand/) on 2021-05-18**:
Thanks to have a look at my problem
There, the links for :
rqt_graph
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuM-59orj0flnZP5ziVCiNd_U5AS9w8j/view?usp=sharing
tf_tree
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cVhrKlboEmmmDvdl058ffIMZJ_6kBI_d/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-05-19**:
Sorry was not able to check that yet, but you have all zero for your covariances. That is a usual source of error, but I doubt that this is the issue here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-20**:
@Bertrand: please do not use off-site hosting for information which is just about central to your problem.

I've attached the screenshots to your post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a typo in both robot_localization configs:  "worl_frame" instead of "world_frame".

I admit it is really hard to see, I wonder if a script like roswtf could automatically catch those, e.g. by checking set parameters against defined parameters.

Please also fix the covariances for odom and imu, they are all zero. See [Considerations for Each Sensor Message Type](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2021-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bertrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/74630/bertrand/) on 2021-05-20**:
Thanks a lot,
I'm sorry for these simple mistakes, I work on it tomorrow
I keep you informed

**Comment by [Bertrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/74630/bertrand/) on 2021-05-21**:
I did outdoor test, it's works very well